# Flutter Error running pod install After Upgrading Flutter version

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

After upgrading the flutter version to the latest Flutter 2.2.1, it gives an error running pod install, on running app on ios simulator

[image]

I have tried cleaning pods by performing the following commands but it did not fix the issue

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
rm ios/Podfile
```

and Finally

```
flutter run
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:
go to ios folder and run

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 1):

run this code on the terminal

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Next, go to the ios folder in your project, and open Podfile.

remove the `#` character and change the `9.0` to `10.0`, and the final code should be like the below

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following set of steps worked for me:

1. Run `flutter clean`
2. Run `flutter pub get`
3. Run `flutter pub upgrade`
4. Delete `Podfile`, `Podfile.lock` and `Pods` folder within ios folder of the project
5. Run `flutter clean`
6. Run `flutter run`