# Flutter ios pod install failed after upgrading Xcode and Flutter version

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

Tried different solution, but nothing works for me.

Sharing links refereed.

[Flutter Error running pod install After Upgrading Flutter version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67885055/flutter-error-running-pod-install-after-upgrading-flutter-version)

**Pod Result**

```
Running "flutter pub get" in firstapp...                         2,706ms
```

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              5.3s
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `fluttertoast` from `.symlinks/plugins/fluttertoast/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `razorpay_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/razorpay_flutter/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:15:in `initialize': undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<String:0x00007fcbdf105240> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:28:in `new'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:28:in `from_file'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:441:in `refresh_metadata'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:56:in `refresh_metadata'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in `repo_information'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in `stack'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in `report'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:15:in `initialize': undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<String:0x00007fcbda2b6c60> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:28:in `new'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:28:in `from_file'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:441:in `refresh_metadata'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:56:in `refresh_metadata'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

**After updating the MAC OS response this**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
```

Running pod install...                                           1,300ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `fluttertoast` from `.symlinks/plugins/fluttertoast/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `razorpay_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/razorpay_flutter/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:15:in `initialize': undefined method` with_indifferent_access' for #String:0x00007fd8f39e86e8 (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:28:in `new' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:28:in` from_file'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:441:in `refresh_metadata' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:56:in` refresh_metadata'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in` initialize'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in` block in source_from_path'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in` block in aggregate_with_repos'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in` aggregate_with_repos'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in` all'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in `repo_information' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in` stack'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in `report' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in` report_error'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in` rescue in run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in` run'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in` load'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:15:in` initialize': undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<String:0x00007fd8f6a9e8a0> (NoMethodError) from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:28:in` new'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:28:in `from_file' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:441:in` refresh_metadata'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:56:in `refresh_metadata' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in` initialize'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in` new'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in` source_from_path'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in` map'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in` aggregate'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in` source_with_url'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in `find_or_create_source_with_url' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in` block in sources'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in` sources'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in `block in resolve_dependencies' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in` section'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in` analyze'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in` block in resolve_dependencies'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in` resolve_dependencies'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in` run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in` run'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>' from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in` load'
from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.2_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Answer (score 2):

Try this on android studio or any-other IDE which you use

1. rm -vrf ~/.cocoapods*
2. brew reinstall cocoapods
3. Delete the Podfile, Podfile.lock, Pods folder, Runner.xcworkspace, Flutter.framwork(in iOS/Flutter folder)
4. flutter clean
5. flutter build iOS

Comment: Save result.

When run with sudo permission. Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install.
  You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
  This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
  This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

Comment: Have tried gem and CocoaPods reinstalled , but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue updating ruby version and install cocoapods

**RVM**

https://rvm.io/rubies/installing

**Cocoapods**

[cocoapods not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904588/cocoapods-not-installing)

Remove cache

```
rm -vrf ~/.cocoapods*
```